# Calculating compound return in a row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame which I need to calculate the compound return over the 3 years.

```
2013     2014     2015     2016      Compound
21480    26384    166760   259842    12.1
104530   92259    80700    79434     0.76
28245    31614.7  29591.3  28557.1   1.01
```

The last column `Compound` is the product of the 2013-16 data in the following formula for the 3rd row:

```
(31614.7/28245) * (29591.3/31614.7) * (28557.7/29591.3) = 1.0111
```

The following is my dumb code:

```
CR <- rep(1,3); 
Compounding_Yrs <- 3;
Annual_Gwth <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3));
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) 
for(j in 1:Compounding_Yrs) 
{
    Annual_Gwth[i,j]<-dt[i,j+1]/dt[i,j]; 
    CR[i]<-CR[i]*Annual_Gwth[i,j]
}
```

`CR` is the compound rate in the last column. My data set `dt` has over 100k rows, so the above code is very slow.

There must be a better way to do this.  Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I did not get the question wrong:

When you chain the compounding between years T1 and T2, the solution boils down to Value at T2 / Value at T1 since the intermediate terms cancel off. For example:

(31614.7/28245) * (29591.3/31614.7) * (28557.7/29591.3) = 1.0111

Boils down to:
28557.7 / 28245 since other terms cancel off.

So my simple solution is to divide the 4th column with the 1st one and record it in the last column. This will also take care of any 0's that may appear in intermediate columns (due to missing data, etc):

```
DF[,5] <- DF[,4] / DF[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to divide last year by first year.

E.g. in row 3:

```
> 28557.1/28245
[1] 1.01105
```

And you don't have to loop over rows. R works well with vectors.

So

```
dt[,4] / dt [,1]
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all at once in a vectorized way (`df` is your data):

```
(df[,2]/df[,1])*(df[,3]/df[,2])*(df[,4]/df[,3])
```